# How can I find the largest and smallest numbers in an object array and change the CSS of that object when it's rendered in React

Tags: reactjs

Here is a mock of what my data looks like, and 3 of the same components.

```
const players = [
    { Fplprice: 7},
    { Fplprice: 4},
    { Fplprice: 10}
];

var largest = Math.max.apply(Math, players.map(function(o) {return o.Fplprice}));
console.log("Largest number is ", largest);

var longest = players.sort(function(a, b) {return a.Fplprice - b.Fplprice})
console.log("Longest number is ", longest);


Return (
<component prop={players[0]}>
<component prop={players[1]}>
<component prop={players[2]}>
)
```

I want to be able to find the max and the min of the object array then pass that info down to child components and render the highest number in green for example and red for the smallest number.

Comment: sort the array First and then use it as you want 
    ```players.sort((a,b) => a.Fplprice - b.Fplprice)``` then the last element will be the max

Comment: Because you haven't shown what you've attempted, I can only provide an initial [pointer](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/reduce) to help you get to the solution.